# Take off (my hat): Place of the adverb particle in the sentence

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Can I say both

> I take my shoe off.

and

> I take off my shoe?

What are the cases where the adverb particle (Is there another name for "adverb/adverbial particles"?)

> Schema 1: Subject + verb + nominal group + adverb particle.
>
> Schema 2: Subject + verb + adverb particle + nominal group.

I want to know if one of them can be said in an informal way. And what are the linguistics rules for the place of the adverb particle, and the exceptions to the rule.

I ask this because I read both in articles and forums.

Comment: Possible duplicate, "down" is "off"? The other thread ask for adverbial particles in general?

Comment: First, "off" is a preposition, not an adverb. Only those prepositions that can come between a verb and its direct object qualify as particles.

Comment: An adverb particle is not an adverb, it's a preposition. I didn't say it was "adverb", but adverb particle, so it's particle. See the definition that has the Oxford dictionary for "off" in "take off", it's an adverbial particle, not a preposition. See wiktionary "Used in many phrasal verbs, off is an adverbial particle often mistakenly thought of as a preposition. (It can be used as a preposition, but such usage is rare and usually informal; see below.)"

Comment: What is an adverbial particle (and not an adverb), see here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/off

Comment: Marking duplicate proves that the people who market it, didn't read the question. The question is about "off" AND the adverbial particles. Show me where it is in another question please.